# Set undeclared search parameter in $state.go ui-router angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set a custom query string parameter during the `$state.go()` call. I would prefer if I did not have to set this parameter for each `$stateProvider.state()`.

An example of this use case would be for setting a `$stateChangeStart` or `$stateChangeSuccess` function to look for a `redirect` parameter of some kind to redirect the transition.

When a user attempts to initially access to your website, but the request is unauthorized, you would redirect them to an authorization/login route. I am currently accomplishing this by a `resolve` in the `$stateProvider.state()` that verifies authorization. If authorization fails, in the `resolve`, I call `$state.go()`. In my attempts to preserve the current state, I get an empty state.

```
$state.current: {
    "name": "",
    "url": "^",
    "views": null,
    "abstract": true
}
```

Also, when I transition to the login route:

```
$state.go('login', {
    redirect: window.location
});
```

The `redirect` query string parameter gets lost. I would love if I did not have to define this for every single `$stateProvider.state()`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do....return user to where they got rejected after the login succeeds?

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, if a `redirect` parameter is defined at any point in the application, pay attention to it

Comment: If you put the authorization resolve in top level abstract and all states that require auth are children should only ever need one auth resolve for whole app. I don't really understand the redirect in login state. Add a `param` to login instead and pass the current state to that param in the resolve.

Answer (score 0):

On latest version of ui-router, all transition syntax was deprecated

legacy $stateChangeStart or $stateChangeSucces, was replaced

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', (evt, toState, toParams, fromState,   
fromParams) => {  
// do something   
});
```

on new version

```
app.run(($transitions) => {   
 $transitions.onStart({ }, (trans) => { 
// **trans** property has .to() & .from() values with all data about state
});  
})
```

read migration [guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks)

Your state config could be:

```
.state({
        name: '**login**',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: your template,
        controller: 'controller name',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        params: {
            **redirect**: null,
        },
    });
```

Comment: I was unaware of the release of v1.0.0, I'll update my code and see if that resolves the undefined initial state issue.

I'm curious if this version will allow access to undefined (in the state) query string parameters

Comment: @Tristian add state config